# Device location path error for navigation of screen in iOS 9

Tags: html, ios, cordova, ios9

In my Cordova based iOS app, when I am trying to navigate to next screen  from home page ,It is remaining in Home page in iOS 9 where as navigation working fine with iOS 8.4 and below.

Here is the path in iOS 8.4(working fine)

> file:///var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/EABC-4728-97BF-466B/MyApp.app/www/**index-telugu.html#publicinterface**

Here is the path in iOS 9.0 which is different from supposed path

> file:///var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/47CF-A77E-97ACED384A/MyApp.app/www/**index-telugu.html#main**

If anyone facing the similar issue Please suggest me the way to solve this

**Here is my code:**

```
    $('#publicinterface_main_id').click(function()
      {

         if (!checkConnection())
        {           
            navigator.notification.alert('Please Check Your Internet Connection');
        }
        else if (!navigator.geolocation) 
        {
            navigator.notification.alert('Please switch on location settings on your mobile');
        }
        else 
        {

            window.location.href = "index-telugu.html#"+$(this).attr('reloadIndex');

            console.log("Path for navigation: : " + window.location.href );

            location.reload();                
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (p) 
            {
                getAddress(p.coords.latitude,p.coords.longitude);
                $('#pub_HgeoLocation').val(p.coords.latitude+","+p.coords.longitude);
            });

         var places = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('pub_geoLocation'));
         google.maps.event.addListener(places, 'place_changed', function () 
            {
                var place = places.getPlace();
                var address = place.formatted_address;
                var longitude = place.geometry.location.lng();
                var latitude = place.geometry.location.lat();
                $('#pub_HgeoLocation').val(latitude+","+longitude)
            });
        }
      });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A bug/"feature" of the iOS 9.0 UIWebView (used by Cordova/Phonegap) is that setting of `window.location.hash` is asynchronous - see [this bug report](https://openradar.appspot.com/22186109) for details. Note that Safari on iOS 8+ uses WKWebView not UIWebView, so this issue is not evident in the Safari browser on iOS 9.0

```
console.log(window.location.hash); // -> "#bar"
window.location.hash = '#foo';

console.log(window.location.hash); 
// -> "#bar" // iOS 9.0 UIWevView
// -> "#foo" // iOS 9.0 WKWebView (Safari) and all other known browsers except

// in all other known browsers at this point window.location.hash will read '#foo'. In iOS9 UIWebView it won't.
if(window.location.hash !== '#foo') {
  // bang: iOS 9 webview
} else {
  // ok: any other browser
}
```

As a workaround, you can try using `window.setTimeout` to make operations following setting the value `window.location.hash` asynchronous, allowing for the value to be applied before you use it. So using your code above, try something like:

```
window.location.href = "index-telugu.html#"+$(this).attr('reloadIndex');

window.setTimeout(function(){
    console.log("Path for navigation: : " + window.location.href );
    location.reload();    
},0);
```

Comment: Thank you ...This has really done a magic for me..It working great with your solution..